# Mysql count transfers between zones

Tags: mysql

I have a big table with many different "trips", I have fields

```
trip_id (number)
fleet_id (number between 1 and 4)
start zone (number between 1 and 999)
end zone (number between 1 and 999)
```

I would like to count how many trips are from zone 1 to zone 1, zone 1 to zone 2...zone 2 to zone 1, zone 2 to zone 2...zone 50 to zone 1 et cetera.
Also both start and end zone could be null.

Comment: Presumably, rows with NULL values are to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
SELECT
    COUNT( trip_id ) AS `count`,
    start_zone, end_zone
FROM
    trips
WHERE 1
    AND start_zone > 0
    AND end_zone > 0
GROUP BY
    start_zone, end_zone
```